# iteration of comparation values in list

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement

I have a list which could change of number of elements

```
list = ['sp', 'gb', 'fr']
```

And I have 3 dictionaries where i can find some information about each country.

```
dic_old_price = {'sp':3355, 'gb': 3000, 'fr':3500}
dic_new_price = {'sp':3005, 'gb': 2500, 'fr':3000}
dic_discount = {'sp': 0.20, 'gb': 0.15, 'fr':0.20}
```

Well, now I want make a condition if where value (old_price*dicount < new_price) then enter the loop, but it must be true for 3 countries (or all we have). Now, I have "if .... and .... and .... :" and I comment conditions if I have only 2 countries, but I can´t do that always.

```
if (dic_old_price[list[1]]*dic_discount[list[1]]) < dic_new_price[list[1]] and (dic_old_price[list[2]]*dic_discount[list[2]]) < dic_new_price[list[2]]: #and (dic_old_price[list[3]]*dic_discount[list[3]]) < dic_new_price[list[3]]:

... could be more than 3 countries...
```

How could I do that? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) with a generator as presented below:

```py
countries = ['sp', 'gb', 'fr']
dic_old_price = {'sp': 3355, 'gb': 3000, 'fr': 3500}
dic_new_price = {'sp': 3005, 'gb': 2500, 'fr': 3000}
dic_discount = {'sp': 0.20, 'gb': 0.15, 'fr': 0.20}


def is_discounted_everywhere(countries, old_prices, new_prices, discounts):
    return all(
        old_prices[country] * discounts[country] < new_prices[country]
        for country in countries
    )


print(is_discounted_everywhere(countries, dic_old_price, dic_new_price, dic_discount))
```

Comment: But i need it as condition for my if loop, how could I implementate this?

Comment: You can use `if is_discounted_everywhere(countries, dic_old_price, dic_new_price, dic_discount):` in your for loop

Answer (score 1):

(note: I changed `list` to `l` to avoid using the keyword).
you could get a list of bool values corrosponding to each index of `l`

```py
tf_lst = [dic_old_price[l[i]]*dic_discount[l[i]] < dic_new_price[l[i]] for i in range(len(l))]
```

and then count how many `True` values are in it

```py
if len([v for v in tf_lst if v]) >= 3:
    # do stuff
```